# pylint giving a number of errors with maximum recursion depth reached

Tags: python, pylint

Pylint gives me an error like this very frequently.

```
shabda@jazzy ~/uswaretech_uswaretechsite> pylint -e utpages/forms.py
No config file found, using default configuration
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'> ignored
```

The logalib mailing list discusses it at http://lists.logilab.org/pipermail/python-projects/2009-March/001789.html , but its a old thread, so has anyone fiund an error like this with Pylint, and found the root cause in ther code?

Comment: I haven't used pylint but apparently it actually imports your file to ananlyse it. HAve you tried using pyflakes to see if the results are similar?

Comment: @noufal-ibrahim: pylint *don't* actually import file (pychecker does that)

Comment: Okay. I'll take your word for it. I thought it did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an [open ticket](http://www.logilab.org/ticket/19641) about this bug. The bug report contains details about the cause.

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been killed in the repository of logilab.astng (dependency of Pylint). You may want to update from source.

logilab-astng mercurial repository at http://www.logilab.org/cgi-bin/hgwebdir.cgi/logilab/astng

@Noufal Ibrahim: pylint tries very hard to to import your module. To my knowledge, it only does so for C extension, for which there is no Python code to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in logilab-astng 0.20 which is out for a year and half.

Upgrading to an earlier release of pylint and logilab-astng should fix the problem.